# thread issue using post

Tags: java, android, multithreading

i am new to android and threading in general. I am currently making a game where the rendering and logic happens on a separate thread from the UI. 
My issue is that i cant seem to update the ui using post from the worker thread.

This is my mainActivity:

```
private GameScene gameScene;
private Handler uiHandler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.game);
    uiHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    gameScene = new GameScene(getApplicationContext(), uiHandler);
    LinearLayout gameHolder = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.game_view);
    gameHolder.addView(gameScene);
    gameScene.resume();
}
```

This is the class which implements runnable:

```
public abstract class Scene extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

    Handler uiHandler;
    Thread thread = null;
    public Scene(Context context, Handler uiHandler) {
        super(context);
        this.uiHandler = uiHandler;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        uiHandler.post(() -> {
            TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.fps_counter);
            textView.setText("hello");
        });
    }

    public void resume() {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/game_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fps_counter"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

The code inside post should run on the ui thread right? But i am getting a null object reference when trying to set the text. And yes the text with id fps_counter exists.

Comment: Try runOnUiThread to run code on the UI thread.

Comment: Please post your layout xml.

Comment: Where should i call it? @Fustigador

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `findViewById` inside your `SurfaceView` effectively looking for a view with given id inside your SurfaceView.

But your view with `R.id.fps_counter` id is inside the activity, so you should look for it in the activity.

I suggest you to find it before creating the `GameScene` class and provide it in the constructor.

See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int) and https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int)

Use the code by petey in the later answer.

**Another solution** would be to pass the activity to your `GameScene`, then you would be able to do it without a handler.

```
private GameScene gameScene;
private TextView fpsCounter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.game);

    fpsCounter = findViewById(R.id.fps_counter);
    gameScene = new GameScene(this);
    LinearLayout gameHolder = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.game_view);
    gameHolder.addView(gameScene);
    gameScene.resume();
}

public void setFps(String fps) {
    fpsCounter.setText(fps);
}
```

and

```
public abstract class Scene extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

    Thread thread;
    Activity activity;

    public Scene(Activity activity) {
        super(activity);
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        activity.runOnUiThread(() -> {
            activity.setFps("Hello");
        });
    }

    public void resume() {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }
```

Even better will be to use constructor expected by the framework and set activity in the init method, like [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setSystemUiVisibility(int))

Answer (score 2):

Since the Gamescene doesn't contain the fps_counter textview, modify your abstract Scene and class extensions so that you can pass a reference to textview.

```
public abstract class Scene extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

    Handler uiHandler;
    Thread thread = null;
    TextView textView;
    public Scene(Context context, Handler uiHandler, TextView textView) {
        super(context);
        this.uiHandler = uiHandler;
        this.textView = textView;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        uiHandler.post(() -> {
            textView.setText("hello");
        });
    }

    public void resume() {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }
```

Then create the GameScene with that 3rd parameter of the textview :

```
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.fps_counter);
// no need to use getApplicationContext(), you may use this (a reference to "mainActivity")
gameScene = new GameScene(this, uiHandler, textView);
```

Comment: Thank you this works. But i have one question, it also works without using a handler. From what i've read you should use a handler to communicate with ui, what can happen if i communicate using plain references to the variables involved instead?

Comment: Yea,  you really don't need that ui handler since the surfaceview callback should/will always be called from a ui thread. If for some reason you call it from a background thread, your app will crash since one of the golden rules is broken (Always touch views from the ui thread.). Glad you are working now.

Comment: Thanks but i still don't quite understand, the purpuse of the run method in scene is that everything in there is executed on a thread different from the ui thread. If i call textView.setText() without uiHandler in run, it is still executed on the ui thread? I am confused now @petey

Comment: It might crash, it might do nothing, it might even work. Check this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44900667/1735198