# Access to UI from background thread android

Tags: android, multithreading

When I try o update the UI from background thread its updating, but I was expecting an exception like *android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.*
Why does this code work?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
lateinit var textView: TextView
lateinit var buttonUIThread: Button
lateinit var buttonAnotherThread: Button

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView)
    buttonUIThread = findViewById(R.id.buttonUIThread)
    buttonAnotherThread = findViewById(R.id.buttonAnotherThread)
}

fun onClick(view: View) {
    when (view) {
        buttonUIThread -> {
            textView.text = "Access to UI from thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}"
        }
        buttonAnotherThread -> {
            Thread {
                textView.text = "Access to UI from thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}"
            }.start()
        }
    }
}
```

}

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZces.png)

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44890807/setting-text-on-textview-from-background-thread-anomaly

Comment: What's the SDK version?